# Value at Risk (VaR): Normal distribution with gamma distributed volatility

Tags: risk-management, value-at-risk, distribution, normal-distribution

If I was to do a 99% VaR calculation on a portfolio with normally distributed returns $\mathcal{N} (\mu,\sigma)$, the 99% VaR would be $\mu - 2.33\sigma$.

Instead of having a constant volatility, let's say volatility is gamma distributed, i.e. $\sigma \sim \Gamma(k, \theta)$.

Explain in as many details as possible (either derive a formula or explain a numerical solution using a computer program) how to compute the VaR of the portfolio when returns have a normal distribution conditional on sigma, and sigma is distributed according to a gamma distribution.

Comment: Just idea: try to generate $\sigma$ from gamma distribution, save it and then generate returns with normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$. Generate another $\sigma$ and so on. Collect set of returns generated in this way and calculate VaR.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [conjugate priors to the normal distribution (with known mean)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) Your setup will result in a $t$-distributed return with updated dispersion parameter.